# In react js, the image does not upload to the firestore database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

As I work on an Instagram clone using React and Firebase, it doesn't seem to be uploading images to my Firebase database.

In my image upload component, I have a progress bar, a caption, and an image upload button. In the first instance, it uploads a null or empty image and in the second instance, it uploads the image that I selected at the beginning or first instance.
Here is my image component

```
  const date = new Date().getTime();
 let storageRef = ref(storage, `post/${date}.png`);

   const upload = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

if (postimg && postcaption) {
  const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, postimg);

  uploadTask.on(
    "state_changed",
    (snapshot) => {
      const progress =
        (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
      console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
      setprogress(progress);
    },
    (error) => {
      // Handle unsuccessful uploads
    },
    () => {
      postUpload();
    }
  );
} else {
  console.log("all feild are mendatory ");
}
};


  const postUpload = async () => {
let url = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
setPosturl(url);
console.log(Posturl);

console.log("i am api link " + Posturl);
let post = await addDoc(posts, {
  caption: postcaption,
  avatar: profileImg,
  post: Posturl,
  username: "username",
});
setpostcaption("");
setprogress(0);
alert("i am upload ");
};
```

Firebase database doesn't show anything being uploaded to the "posts" collection and the second instance the image url at post that I selected at first instance isn't being uploaded.
I am not sure if that is an issue with my ImageUpload or Firebase.

Comment: What is firebase version you use?

Comment: sir i am using   "firebase": "^9.9.2",

Comment: Would I know please where do you define `storageRef`?

Comment: sure sir  but how can i show you here .

Comment: i dont know how to use stackoverflow.

Comment: sir i define storageRef outside the both function at global scope

Comment: Just edit the question, and add the code inside.

Comment: sir now you good to go !

Comment: It should work fine, Are you sure the `if` condition is `truthy`? And doesn't get uploaded to the `post` bucket on firebase?

Comment: Sir so why At **second** time it upload initial one

Comment: May because the image size is small, do you try to upload a large image? ( for example bigger than 4MB )